# Incompatibility between marks on curve and legend

Tags: pgfplots, legend, mark

I have a new star style defined in pgfplots. The positions of the stars on the curve is correct but in the legend is wrong.

The code and figure are below. The position of the star in the legend is wrong. How to fix it?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    dashstar/.style={
        dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt,
        postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
                mark=between positions 7.5pt and 1 step 10pt with {
                    \node {\pgftransformscale{0.6}\pgfuseplotmark{star}};}}}},
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{lines}{
    {green,solid, very thick},
    {red, dashdotted, very thick},
    {black, dashstar, very thick},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={$x^2$,$2x^2$,$4x^2$},
cycle list name=lines]
\addplot{x^2};
\addplot{2*x^2};
\addplot{4*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a lower level decoration commands for the stars, the issue does not to arise. First a minimal damage fix to your code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    dashstar/.style={
        dash pattern=on 5pt off 5pt,
        postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
                mark=between positions 7.5pt and 1 step 10pt with {
                    \begin{pgfscope}
                    \pgftransformscale{0.6}\pgflowlevelsynccm\pgfuseplotmark{star}
                    \end{pgfscope}}}}},
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{lines}{
    {green,solid, very thick},
    {red, dashdotted, very thick},
    {black, dashstar, very thick},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={$x^2$,$2x^2$,$4x^2$},
cycle list name=lines]
\addplot{x^2};
\addplot{2*x^2};
\addplot{4*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\pgflowlevelsynccm` is not absolutely essential but it makes the downscaled stars still look like stars. If you remove it, you'll get still correct placement but the stars look more like real stars, namely round.

[image]

Personally I'd also recommend to choose a different way of declaring the `dashstar` pattern, as that seems to be more robust according to my own experience.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{stars}{initial}{\state{initial}[width=6pt,next state=star1]
{
}
\state{star1}[width=4pt,next state=gap]
{  
   \begin{pgfscope}
   \pgftransformscale{0.6}
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \pgfuseplotmark{star}
   \end{pgfscope}
  }
\state{gap}[width=4pt,next state=star1]
{
  }
\state{final}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
}  

}

\tikzset{
dashstar/.style={dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,postaction={decorate,decoration=stars}}
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{lines}{
    {green,solid, very thick},
    {red, dashdotted, very thick},
    {black, dashstar, very thick},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-3:3,
legend pos=outer north east,
legend cell align={left},
legend entries={$x^2$,$2x^2$,$4x^2$},
legend image code/.code={%
                    \draw[#1] (0cm,0.01cm) -- (0.7cm,0.01cm);
                }, 
cycle list name=lines]
\addplot{x^2};
\addplot{2*x^2};
\addplot{4*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But that's of course completely up to you.